# Convert a text cell formatted as "1h 25m" to 85m

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date-time

I would like to convert a cell with the following text/numeric string 1h 25min to a cell that displays 85min. Unfortunately, the original cell is only in the 1h 25min format and not in a true excel time format.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's text representing a time in an unrecognized format, you need to dissect it manually using Excel's string utilities.

Here's an example formula that will section out the hours and minutes and then convert it to a standard "Time" type.  This assumes your time string is in cell A1:

`=TIME(LEFT(A1, FIND("h ",A1)-1), MID(A1,FIND("h ",A1)+3, FIND("min",A1)-5),0)`

As-is it's not very dynamic; it expects the format to be as you laid it out, including 2 digits for the minutes, but should be enough to get you going.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have created a simple excel spreadsheet and entered the text as 1h 25m in the cell. Using A2 as my return cell I have entered your formula. I received the trusted #value response. Not sure why it is not calculating an 85m response in A2. You are correct in assuming the format is one digit for the hours and two digits for the minutes. Any possible ideas to get #value to go away? @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007